# In-App Billing Ads removal: Ads are not showing

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, admob, in-app-billing

I am trying o implement In-App Billing in my App, and the in app billing itself is working fine.

But while it should disable the Ads **only for premium users**, I somehow disabled them completely. I'll post my code to better let you understand:

This is my `IabPurchaseFinished()` method:

```
@Override
public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info) {

    if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(info)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_purchasing, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.premium_bought, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (info.getSku().equals("chords_premium")) {

        /** salva isPremium tra SharedPreferences */
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("status", "purchased");
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

As you can see it saves the string value *status* to *SharedPreferences* as *purchased*.

now in the Activity where I have my Ads I did it like this:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.getString("status", "free");


    /** gestisce le pubblicita */
    if (prefs.equals("free")) {
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-6723047396589178/2654753246");

        AdView listBanner = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.chords_list_banner);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        listBanner.loadAd(adRequest);

        /** carica Ad a tutto schermo */
        chordsListAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        chordsListAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-6723047396589178/7447672046");
        requestNewInterstitial();


        chordsListAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
            }
        });
    }
```

As you can se I first check my `*SharedPreferences*` to see if there is *"status"* and if there's not I set it to *"free"*

Then I have my Ads in an `if` statement:

```
if (prefs.equals("free"))
```

So, I think they are shown if the string in SharedPreferences is "free" or, in other words, it's not "purchased", that means that the user has not bought the in App.

**The problem is that no matter if I access with an account that has the In App or not, the Ads will not be shown. Any Idea on how I could fix it?**

Obviously I have tested with Signed Apk uploaded on the Developer console, with everything set up according to the [testing In-App Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) guidelines by google.

Answer (score 1):

You did a small mistake here:

```
if (prefs.equals("free"))
```

`prefs` is as defined `SharedPreferences prefs` which is never a `String` and this means it is always `false`.

What you really want to write is this check:

```
String status = prefs.getString("status", "free");

/** gestisce le pubblicita */
if (status.equals("free")) {
```